# importing exsiting svn project to github repo

Tags: svn, github, git-svn

this is my first time trying to use github so please bear with me..

Currently, I am managing my project through tortoise SVN.

I have created a repository on github and tried to uploaded a readme file through instructions given on github help

Iam tryin to import existing svn project to github repository and its giving me errors.
Since Iam new to github, I am unable to figure it out...

any idea????

[image: erros while git svn clone to github repo]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before debugging the certificate validation error, please note that the [GitHub page](http://help.github.com/import-from-subversion/) mentions:

> git-svn can be used to import as well. Note that there may be issues if you have branches or tags (they won’t be imported over). If you only have a trunk, like many svn repositories, this method should work for you without issue.
>
> First, be sure to create your repository on GitHub

```
$ git svn clone -s SVN_REPO_URL LOCAL_DIR
$ cd LOCAL_DIR
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:GITHUB_USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git
$ git push origin master
```

So the `git svn clone -s SVN_REPO_URL LOCAL_DIR` command needs a `SVN_REPO_URL` (as in "SVN", not Git)

https://github.com/healthpark/Healthpark.ca.git is the name of a Git repo, not an SVN repo.